# In java spring hibernate 3.6.3 how to tell a method to wait until lock is aqured and how to retry a failed transaction?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my spring application I am facing failed to acquire lock issue and transaction is getting failed. It is not even rollbacking the transaction as database is not providing the lock. How to tell a method to wait until the lock is acquired? I am using hibernate and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to use `@Transactional` as method/class annotation in the case of spring.

By default, we have the propagation REQUIRED `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`. Spring checks if there is an active transaction, then it creates a new one if nothing existed.
[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation) you can find the explanation of spring transaction propagations.

First, you have to take a look and analyze what you need there to use.

Please tell us, where do you face with lock issues?
Probably you have to deal with the Isolation levels; We can deal with them at mySql, hibernate or spring level.
Here we need to know where you have configurations for isolation (mySql, hibernate or spring).

You can check if you need to [update the lock timeout](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking), using `QueryHints`.

```
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "3000")})
public Optional<Customer> findById(Long customerId);
```

Comment: An easy way would be to catch the exception, do a wait and try again. But there should be a better way of doing this.

Comment: I am getting lock aquire timeout exception when trying to perform a insert operation. The problem is, I am performing insert operation by Dao.save(obj) method. Here there is no way to pass query hints because this save method is shared for all insert operation for any tables.

Comment: I have also marked @Transactional for the parent method but this still producing the error.

Comment: There should be a way of updating the timeout value.

Comment: Is it possible to set a retry ?

Comment: That would be the last solution; having a try-catch with retry. I would try to extend the timeout value.